# .Net NuGet package conflicts - DLL Hell is back

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-spec

I have a Visual Studio project.
It requires the Newtonsoft.Json library.
It is referenced with the NuGet package manager of Visual Studio 2017.
Actually the version 10.0.3.

This project is referencing the NuGet package LibA and LibB.

LibA uses Newtonsoft.Json version 8 and this is defined in the package.nuspec:

```
<dependency id="RestSharp" version="105.2.3" />
<dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" />
<dependency id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" />
```

LibB uses NewtonSoft.Json version 10 and this is defined in the package.nuspec:

```
<dependency id="RestSharp" version="105.1" />
<dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" />
```

When I update the LibA package (for example from version 1.1 to 1.2) using the NuGet Package Manager of Visual Studio 2017 (on the solution)
it updates the reference of the LibA package as expected in the .csproj file:

```
 -  <HintPath>..\packages\LibA.1.1\lib\net40\MyService.dll</HintPath>
 +  <HintPath>..\packages\LibA.1.2\lib\net40\MyService.dll</HintPath>
```

but it also update the reference of the Newtonsoft.Json library:

```
-  <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
-  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
+  <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
+  <HintPath>..\packages\LibA.1.2\lib\net40\\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
```

and the app/web.config file:

```
-  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
+  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
```

It also update correctly the LibA reference in the package.config:

```
 -  <package id="LibA.MyService" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
 +  <package id="LibA.MyService" version="1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

but it leaves the WRONG reference to the Newtonsoft.Json library version:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net47" />
```

**I complain about 2 things:**

1. If I open the NuGet Package Manager it is showing that I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json version 10.0.3 in the current project:
   this is not true because when I build the solution in the bin folder it is stored version 8.0.3
   and it is not possible to update the Newtonsoft.Json because it is "already" updated.
   Furthermore my project and the LibB that needs the vesion 10 are actually using version 8.
2. I cannot decide to maintain the version 10 automatically, **actually I have to merge and correct manually all the .config and .csproj files** !

There is a way to avoid this nightmare?

Extra info.
The project and the LibB are set on .Net 4.7.
LibA is still on .Net 4.5.
LibA and LibB are deployed in the company NuGet repository.

**[Update]**
As suggested in the comments I'll try to NOT include the Newtonsoft.Json library in the LibA (and LibB) packages. Actually it happens because of this (I think):

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\**\*.*" exclude="**\*.pdb" target="lib\net40"/>     
  </files>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\**\MyCompany.*.*" exclude="**\*.pdb" target="lib\net40"/>     
</files>
```

and it works, the Newtonsoft.Json package is taken from NuGet.

Comment: Are you able to use the new csproj format? No hint paths, and it seems to be better at coping with this...

Comment: It looks like LibA is including Newtonsoft.Json.dll in its own nupkg file btw, which may be responsible for the problem.

Comment: Can you re write liba nuget package to reference newtonsoft Json instead of copying the DLL?

Comment: Hi Jon, the project is created in VS2013 or VS2015 but now I'm coding it with VS2017. Actually it is a solution with some projects. I can add a new Test project freshly created with VS 2017, is this the way to create the NEW .csproj format ? What exactly do you mean? Do you have a link? Yes, both the libraries are including the Newtonsoft and RestSharp libraries in different versions. I cannot change that, it is normal practice. What I don't like is that VS is changing the path from MY package folder (that already have Newtonsoft) to the one contained in the 3rd party NuGet package. thanks

Comment: Hi @dariogriffo. I cannot change the LibA, it is not mine. Do you mean to include in <files> only MyCompany.**.dll and rely on the <dependency> for get Newtonsoft and other libraries that exists in NuGet ? I'll try on a different project. Many thanks.

Comment: I asked to the other team to change the nuspec file removing the "external" DLL (I have done this before, I forgot how it works). I'm still not happy with the default behavior of VS + NuGet Package Manager.
If someone post this suggestion as new reply I'll be happy to mark it as right solution for benefit to others that came here with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first complaint is not correct. The NuGet Package Manager shows you what version of the *NuGet package*, not the version number embedded in the DLL. You could argue that the Package Manager should detect this, but it's really an edge case caused by a bad `LibA` package.

You are correct about the fix: `<file src="bin\$configuration$\**\*.*" exclude="**\*.pdb" target="lib\net40"/>` should not be used.
Ideally, you only include the assemblies produced by building the project. If you include dependencies, both internal (e.g. `MyCompany.Common.dll`) or external (e.g. `OtherCompany.dll`), you risk running into this problem. Put the dependencies on an internal NuGet server.